# backbone collection url manipulation with input field text

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone. I have a collection whose url function depends on the textfield text. How do i get that text from my textfield. No i don't want to use JQuery selectors as accessing outside selectors from your views aint a good practice. My HTML stucture is like:

```
<div id='outer'>
    <input type='text' id='xyz'>
    <div id='image123'></div>
    <div id='div1'>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='div2'></div>
</div>
```

So i got 2 views, 1 collections & 1 model.
How do i get the input text in the collection without using JQuery selectors from my 'outer' view.

[Post updated with View code]

```
var outerView = Backbone.View.extend
({
    el: '#outer',

    initialize: function()
    {

    },

    events:
    {
        'keyup #xyz' : 'keyfunc'
    },

    keyfunc: function()
    {
        // inputtext is a global variable & i don't want it that way
        inputtext = $('#xyz').val();    
    },

    render: function()
    {

    },
});
```

Comment: why cant you get the text directly form your 'inner' view?

Comment: I don't want to access outer elements from my inner views. My div1 is a view itself which will have to user JQuery to access outer elements, i don't want that. And also i havnt used any events untill now to make my inner views interact.

Comment: in which view is the textfield?

Comment: outer div i.e. the top most view

Comment: so what is the problem from accessing it from you top most view? , if you cant do that show your views so that i can help

Comment: my current way is getting the text & storing it as a global variable and later using it in the collection. I want to directly pass it to the collection's url function rather than having a global variable. (Updating the post with the view- Check)

Comment: You should never access anything of an 'outer' view' from an 'inner' view. You should structure your code better, if you want to avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure what are you doing , but only if you want to send the value to the collection with out making it global and changing the url ,try doing it this way

```
    var outerView = Backbone.View.extend
({
    el: '#outer',

    initialize: function()
    {

    },

    events:
    {
        'keyup #xyz' : 'keyfunc'
    },

    keyfunc: function()
    {
        // not global now
        var inputtext = $('#xyz').val();  
        var myclooction  = new MainCollection({
        text : inputtext
         });

    },

    render: function()
    {

    },
});
```

in the collection

```
var MainCollection = Backbone.extend.collection({
    url : function(){
       return "someurl/"+this.text;
    },
    // receive the value here
    initialize:function(options){
     this.text = options.text;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahaan! Bang on. Thanks a lot buddy. Exactly what i wanted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Backbone passes information about the element that triggered the event, and there you can find that value like so:

```
keyfunc: function(e)
{
    inputtext = $(e.currentTarget).val();  
    this.model.trigger('textChanged', {id: this.myID, data: inputtext});  
}
```

and your model can listen that event like this in its initialize-function.

```
this.listenTo(this, 'textChanged', this.textChangedHandler);
```

And the model can then decide what to do with that event. For example to send it to that another view by another event.

```
textChangeHandler: function (e) {
    this.trigger('someTextChanged', e);
}
```

And your views or collections can listen that event in their initialize-function:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'someTextChanged', this.textChangedHandler);
```

And the handler would be something like:

```
textChangeHandler: function (e) {
    if (e.id !== this.myID) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh dude dude. My problem is not assigning the value to a variable, its the way i pass the variable to my collection's url function; without making it global !

Comment: You can trigger an event that sends the value.

Comment: Can you let me know how ?